# Want to display fitting equation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, equation

I am fitting data with an equation and I would like to display that fitting equation.

the following doesn't seem to display y_equation (everything else works). Ideas?

```
data = np.loadtxt("datafile.dat")
x= data[:,0]
y= data[:,1]
plt.scatter(x,y)


x_equation = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y_equation = np.sin(x_equation)      # of course this is actually very long and messy

plt.plot(x_equation,y_equation)
plt.text(y_equation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just use your variable `y_equation` for the text. One way is to explicitly write the equation as a string. In that case, you need to specify the x and the y-coordinate for positioning the string and then the string using `plt.text` as following. Let me know if you need something else.

```
x_equation = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y_equation = np.sin(x_equation)      

plt.plot(x_equation,y_equation)
plt.text(4, 0.75, 'sin(x)', fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much that works well. However, my equation is usually very long and cumbersome, some 10+ terms. I wasn't sure if there is an easy way to reference my fitting question without having to type it again? some way of referencing y_equation without a separate retype. This serves as a check if my equation is typed correctly also. ?  can I do something like a = str(y_equation) and then plt.text(a) ?